# ReactiveUI binding with dependencyproperty and pass to viewmodel

Tags: reactiveui

I started using ReactiveUI (with WPF) for first time and have little problem which I couldn't google out or find on docs. How do you bind properties from Control's DependencyProperty?

I'm creating a user control

```
public partial class MotorControlView: ReactiveUserControl<MotorControlViewModel>
```

and inside the class I have dependency property MotorAxis

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MotorAxisProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MotorAxis", typeof(MotorAxis), typeof(MotorControlView));

public MotorAxis MotorAxis
{
    get => (MotorAxis) GetValue(MotorAxisProperty);
    set => SetValue(MotorAxisProperty, value);
}
```

Inside the view there is TextBlock which should show `MotorAxis` (it's an enum) string value (NoVal/X/Y/Z). 
The property is set in `MainWindow.XAML`  ( `<uc:MotorControlView MotorAxis="Y" />` )

**The problem is:**

- how do I bind label's text to MotorAxis control's property using ReactiveUI?
- how do I pass the value to ViewModel

In the constructor its value is always default (NoVal), so I think I can't pass it to viewmodel constuctor...

The ViewModel will be responsible for accessing X/Y/Z motor based on this parameter

---

The only solution I got found out is doing so:

```
//In View:
public MotorControlView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new MotorControlViewModel();
    this.WhenActivated(dr =>
    {
        ViewModel.MotorAxis = this.MotorAxis;
    });
    this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.MotorAxis, v => v.MotorAxisBlock.Text);
}
```

//In VM:
property with 
`this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref this.motorAxis, value)`

Is there a more elegant way to do this without manually setting value in WhenActivated? So I will have this value accessible in eg. VM's constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactiveui uses code behind bindings.

Typically you would place these in the constructor.

Main advantage of the reactiveui way is type safety.

```cs
public MotorControlView
{
  this.Bind(this.ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.Axis, view => view.MotorControl.Text, axis => axis.ToString(), axisString => (MotorAxis)Enum.Parse(typeof(MotorAxis), axisString);
}
```

The above is doing Bind in the constructor. The following parameters are passed:

1. The view model
2. A expression pointing towards the property on the view model
3. A expression pointing towards the property on the view
4. A converter method taking the property on the view model, converting to a string and putting that on the view
5. A converter method taking the string on the view and converting to the enum on the view model.

See https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/ for further info.

Comment: yeah, but how about this dependencyProperty? Is there a way to initialize VM's MotorAxis property without manually 
`this.WhenActivated(d => { ViewModel.MotorAxis = this.MotorAxis; });` ?

Comment: you can just change the ViewModel binding to be `view => view.MotorAxis` in the third parameter above. Then you can have another Bind/OneWayBind to your View object.